# Select Radio Button using Robot framework

Tags: frameworks, robotframework

I have this HTML code:

`<td><input name="selFundDetails" type="radio"></td>`

I am trying to set the radio button using the keyword "Select Radio Button" to set the value to "Yes".

I tried using:

```
Select Radio Button selFundDetails  Yes
```

I am getting error as:

```
20160316 16:17:38.216 :  INFO : Verifying element 'selFundDetails' is visible.
20160316 16:17:38.362 :  INFO : Selecting 'true' from radio button 'selFundDetails'.
20160316 16:17:38.667 :  FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//input[@type='radio' and @name='selFundDetails' and (@value='true' or @id='true')]' did not match any elements.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select radio button does not work sometimes, if the requirement is to select a radio button, then "click element   " will work.

Answer (score 3):

Your radio button doesn't have a `value` or `id`, which is required for `Select Radio Button` to know which radio button you want it to click. Your `name=selFundDetails` only tells the keyword which group you are targeting.

From the [Selenium2LibraryDocs](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Radio%20Button):

> Select Radio Button
>
> Sets selection of radio button group identified by group_name to value.
>
> The radio button to be selected is located by two arguments:
>   `group_name` is used as the name of the radio input,
>   `value` is used for the value attribute or for the id attribute
>
> The XPath used to locate the correct radio button then looks like this: `//input[@type='radio' and @name='group_name' and (@value='value' or @id='value')]`
>
> Examples:
>
> `Select Radio Button   size    XL  # Matches HTML like <input type="radio" name="size" value="XL">XL</input>`
>
> `Select Radio Button   size    sizeXL  # Matches HTML like <input type="radio" name="size" value="XL" id="sizeXL">XL</input>`

If you control the html, then you can add a `value="Yes"` attribute to your radio button and your keyword will work.

If you do not control the html, god help you. But you should be able to click it with a pure `Click Element` (by xpath).