# Select radio button with robotframework

Tags: python-2.7, radio-button, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to select a radio button using `Robotframework(Python2.7,Selenium2Library)`.

I have the following code:

```
<div id="dt_method_cashondelivery" class="u-border-b-dotted u-space-pt-10                                                       
 u-space-pb-5">
     <input id="p_method_cashondelivery" class="Form-check-toggle"  
 type="radio"title="Cash On Delivery" name="payment[method]"           
 value="cashondelivery"/>
     <label class="Form-radio" for="p_method_cashondelivery">
         <span>Cash On Delivery </span>
     </label>
 </div>
```

The Robot Framework code I am using is:

```
Select Radio Button    payment[method]    cashondelivery
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly state the problem. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: What code are you using to click on the radio button?

Comment: I used Select Radio Button with arguments groupname=payment[method] and value=cashondelivery.

Comment: I get the following error : ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//input[@type='radio' and @name='payment[method]' and (@value='cashondelivery' or @id='cashondelivery')]' did not match any elements.

Comment: Try without setting explicit equals to; so for example: `Select Radio Button | payment[method] | cashondelivery` dont think it'll work but It's strange (for me) to see it like that

Comment: Same error with the sollution you provided.

Comment: Replace the `cashondelivery` with `p_method_cashondelivery` - lets see if using the ID can help

Comment: OK - After looking around I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027433/select-radio-button-using-robot-framework So maybe try a `Click Element` keyword on the Xpath of that Radio Button.

Comment: Ok so it passed my test but in the browser it didnt check my the button.

Comment: Try clicking on the text instead of the radio button instead? I have no idea why its passing but not actually clicking the radio button. Its like its not registering it or something :( Jiggle the Xpath around, Id say...

Comment: Try `Mouse Down` instead of `Click Element` - Maybe we need to physically stimulate a left click... Remember to do `Mouse Up` straight after too - to remove the mouse click being held down - Also are you able to edit the HTML code?

Comment: I do not have acces to edit the code

Comment: I will try the Mouse down option see if that works

Comment: Not working WebDriverException: Message: POST /session/a407c3c8-f794-4779-a0e0-623947eda450/moveto did not match a known command.

Comment: I used mouse down with argument xpath=//input[@type='radio' and @name='payment[method]' and (@value='p_method_cashondelivery' or @id='p_method_cashondelivery')]

Comment: Which browser is this?

Comment: Wait - Is there any kind of <form> tag anywhere within this HTML page? If not - then there's your issue. EDIT: Maybe... Lemme look into it.

Comment: I am using firefox. And actually i have `<div id="js-payment-form">` at the start of the code that i attached .

Comment: OK - I know there are issues with IE and Edge so thats fine - Thats still a div though, not a form. I think Selenium2 is getting confused because its a radio button outside a form. Make a `<div>` with a ID which hsa the name "Form" - Doesnt make it a `<form>`

Comment: I do not have acces to edit the code.

Comment: Then I have no idea how you're going to be able to select something which Selenium doesn't really understand how to interact with.. :( Sorry :( - I would recommend you talk to the people who manage the code to make edits of some kind - But I seriously have no clue :(

Comment: Ok i will talk with my dev team to see if we can modify something in the code. Anyway thank you a lot man for the help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Anytime :) come back if you find anything / change something :) And you too!

Answer (score 1):

Use below keyword

```
Click Element    jquery=#p_method_cashondelivery
```

OR

```
Click Element    css=#p_method_cashondelivery
```

If you are locating element using **id** attribute then precede it with **'#'** and if you are locating element using **class** then precede with **'.'**